Local Record with type of generic method
Why is not possible to create a local record that contains fields corresponding to the generic type of the method?
Not working example:
public class Test {

   <T> void foo(T param) {
       record Container(T content) { }
       Container test = new Container(param);
   }
}

I get the error: non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context.
Working but in my opinion unnecessary:
public class Test {

   <T> void foo(T param) {
       record Container<S>(S content) { }
       Container<T> test = new Container<>(param);
   }
}


Your goal appears strange, but you should include the error in the problem too. Are you getting non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context

@matt I am getting "'T' cannot be referenced from a static context".
In the comments of one of the answers, Sweeper points out that making the record local only changes its visibility but otherwise it is the same as a nested record (which i know are always static). This explains the error message and the behaviour to me.
My example is only a minimal case of my use case, i ackknowledge that it does not make much sense as it is.

Nested Records are implicitly static, so you cannot use the runtime generic value. interfaces have the same issue. So this could be a good question since records are new and I cannot find the duplicate. Can you include the error? Maybe change it to a singly nested class.

They discuss it a bit in 8.1.1.4

Records should be defined outside of methods. They need to be visible to the entire class.

@matt I put the compiler error in the question now. Do you want me to change anything else? If I understand you correctly you want this to be easily findable for future reference. If it helps, feel free to edit anything you want. You and Sweeper answered my question in the comments.

For people voting to close this question, I think it's not opinion-based as it's asking why this error appear, and try to understand.

I think that putting a normal class with a nested record defined has the same problems. It is also a pretty common thing. Your example is very odd because the scope of the record is so limited.  eg class Test<T>{ record TR(T t){}} fails, but Test<T>{ record TR<S>(S s){}is ok

As others have said, records are implicitly static, which means even though the record class is inside the foo method, it doesn’t know about the foo method’s existence (or the existence of the instance whose foo method was called).  Therefore, it doesn’t know what T is.

Would people who voted to close this please elaborate how this is opinion based? There is a reason why this does not work and it has nothing to do with opinion. See the accepted answer. I hope it is not because the question contained the word "opinion"..

A record isn't just a drop in replacement of a class.
public class Recorded<T>{
    class Bc{
        T t; 
    }
    record Br(T t){};
}

The class will compile file, but the record fails because

|  non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context
|      record Br(T t){};

That is because records cannot be inner classes, or they are implicitly static.
For OP's case, the record is being limited in scope but it obeys the same rules. Essentially, since a record is not an inner class you cannot make a concrete type from a generic.
Here is the related question about interfaces

Thank you for taking your time answering this. The method where i stumbled upon this was not as odd as the one i gave above. I just broke it down as much as possible to capture the essence of it without too much stuff around it.
I really want to understand the details of the language I use, that is why I asked this question. Thanks again and have a nice day.

You are creating a record in the foo method. This will create as a new class. If you are using the type T, it will failed because this type can change each method call.
When using record Container<S>(S content) { }, you are creating a new static type in the method. When using the type T, you are using a non-static type. Similar issue can appear with the final keyword. Sometimes, if a variable isn't final, it could not be used. You have to create a second variable, which is final. In your case, the type create to be final is S.
To be able to use the type T, you can use the S's one that will take "a picture" of the actual T type (which is the same as making variable final), for example:
public class Test {

   <T> void foo(T param) {
       record Container<S extends T>(S content) { }
       Container<T> test = new Container<>(param);
   }
}

In this case, the type S should be the type T or a sub class of it. And, even by changing the type T the compiler would not care as it already choose a not-changing type, and set as static type use by this record.

Sorry I still don't understand this. I am aware that the type of T can change each method call. But what if it is exactly the point of this local record to always just capture this changing type. I don't understand why the compiler does not allow this.

@LukasBetz A local record is no different from a record nested in the enclosing class. The fact that you put it in a method only changes where its name can be used. This works with classes because inner classes are a thing, but not "inner records".

I just added few explaination about this @LukasBetz . I hope it well answer and you understand it, also sadly I don't have like java's documentation link to explain this better

@Sweeper Ah, that explains it, i did not know that it only changed visibility but nothing else.

I think you're missing the point. Records are implicitly static. I don't think the 'extends T' is adding anything because they create a version with T as the generic. Most likely I am missing your point though.

By using extends T, it create a static type S that require the dynamic type T. I tried on my IDE and it works fine

I don't see what it adds.

I hope I'm well explaining, I just edited my answer

The problem I see with your answer is, I can do it with a class. class Container{ final T a; Container(T a){this.a = a;} }
